# Is there a way to protect against fake messages by an SPA that consumes a webservice directly?

Tags: web-service, single-page-app

I develop a webservice currently and communication might be a bottleneck. It would be at least 100ms faster if I could access the webservice from the browser directly instead of sending the messages to the consumer's server first and relaying them to the webservice along with the consumer identifier.

If I store that consumer identifier in the SPA, then everybody could fake a request in the name of the consumer, they just need to check what the SPA sends to the webservice as an user of it. Is there a way to protect the webservice against these kind of fake messages?

Edit:

Sorry, I forgot to add important details:

- The webservice is not typical, I don't have a main site like facebook, all the users are registered to the webservice through consumers who will need the service to earn money, so I guess they can be trusted more or less, but somebody can add a consumer if they pay the price and can start to hack the system as a consumer. So the question does not have anything to do about allowing an untrusted 3rd party client to access the profile page, photo albums, etc. of an already registered user e.g. with oauth.
- I send the user credentials (or auth token) with each message, so user identification is not a problem.
- Reusing registrations among consumers would be a nice feature, but I am not sure if it involves security issues.
- I'll write some of the clients in the beginning, but if the service grows big, I won't be able to check the code each of the clients, so some of them can contain vulnerabilities.

I think a real threat would be somebody who gets some of the consumer ids and user credentials e.g. with a fake login page and starts to send messages to the webservice in the name of different consumer and user combinations. If I make the consumer ids public, then that would be a lot easier to do. I don't know what I could do in such scenario, how to separate the fake from real messages, etc. so it would be nice to avoid that scenario or have a plan for it, or both. Ofc. an attacker could use the client of the consumer instead of sending fake messages directly, but that feels something easier to control. I don't know why, I need to think about this a lot more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this and the answer is no. It is not possible to decide the identity of the consumer by pure SPA clients. Even if I have fully trusted consumers where the users can register and login, it is better not to share the user accounts between them, because that way a compromised consumer can send requests in the name of any other consumer simply by knowing the user credentials. If I have not-trusted consumers, then an oauth like solution is the only option, which can be inconvenient if we want to make registration simple. Note that in this scenario the user does not know anything about the webservice, it visits the site of the consumer directly.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear, your scenario is:

- You have a web service, which requires authentication to use.
- Your customer has a web app, the server of which acts as a client of your web service.
- You are looking to allow your customer's users to interact with your web service directly having their browsers act as the client (presumably via CORS request).
- You want to prevent your customer's users from making arbitrary requests to your web service using your customer's authorization.

Is that all correct? If so, you're in a tricky spot. Broadly speaking, that is of course impossible; any request a web app can make, a user can open the browser's developer console and re-play, tweak, read the result of, etc. Anything the web app can add for authentication or authorization - headers, cookies, secret tokens or HMACs or whatever - the user can tell the web app to add to their own message.

There are things you can do that might be sufficient in this case, though. You can have your customer give different authorization tokens to each user (assuming your server can validate them all), so that if some user abuses the service you can tell who. If you're worried about too many requests flooding the server, you can throttle requests by authorization token and/or source IP. You can scope the customer's authorization down to only APIs and data the customer needs, preventing the users from making actually arbitrary calls. You can even combine that last option in a hybrid approach; users receive a token that can make some low-risk calls directly, and all others have to bounce off the customer's server.

More specific advice would require more information about what you are trying to secure, and why. In general, though, there's no way to tell whether a request comes from an authorized client or somebody who is misusing (or cloning) that client, and that's especially true when the official client is a web app.

Comment: "Tell the webapp to add to their request" is a bit of a stretch, but "construct a request with those features" is certainly accurate.

Comment: Eh, it's not commonly done, but it's not like it's *hard* to hijack standard JS functions (like `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`) in a a third-party web app, just using the browser's dev tools, and make them modify the request before sending. But yeah, you wouldn't need to bother.

Comment: I edited the question. I am not sure if it can be answered, probably better to delete it, idk.

Comment: @CBHacking Not hard, no, but that's not really "telling the webapp" is it? Yes, writing that down it _does_ seem incredibly pointless to quibble over that, so I'm just gonna... drop the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of three legged application is what OAuth2 are designed for.

I would suggest looking into implementing OAuth2 into your application.